# Cannot invoke value of type

Tags: swift

I was trying to append my Point array with some data, although I got an error of type, shown below. Appreciate any help, thanks!

```
for i in slew {
    var x = i[0]
    var y = i[1]
        pointsArray.append(Points.GetPoint(origin:Points.Point(x:x,y:y))) //Cannot invoke value of type 'Points.GetPoint.Type' with argument list '(origin: Points.Point)'

}


class Points: NSObject {
    struct Point {
        var x = Double(0.0)
        var y = Double(0.0)
    }

    struct GetPoint {
        var origin = Point()

        var point: Point {
            get {
                let x = origin.x
                let y = origin.y
                return Point(x:x, y:y)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `pointsArray` declared?

Comment: this goes before the original code
`
        var pointsArray: [Points.Point] = []
        
        
        var slew = [[Double]]()
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            var subSlew = [Double]()
            for _ in 0..<2 {
                subSlew.append(0)
            }
            slew.append(subSlew)
        }`

Comment: `struct GetPoint` doesn't make sense

Comment: @Tony You cannot append a `Points.GetPoint` to a `Points.Point` array. Although I'm not really sure why you have two different types to represent a point – I'm assuming this is a simplified example?

Comment: @Tony This code needs quite a bit of clean up. We would be able to help you if we better understood what you're trying to do

Comment: Why not simply `typealias Point = CGPoint` ? ;-)

Comment: @Alexander
i would like to create an object(class/struct) Point with x and y coords. Therefore, I would like to create array[Point] and add there all my coords pairs

Comment: Tony what data type should the `x` and `y` have? `Float`, or `Double`?

Comment: @Alexander should be `Double`

Comment: @Tony Okay, so just make a struct containing the two members: `struct Point { let x: Double; let y: Double }`. What need is there for `class Points`, or `struct GetPoint`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the code should look like, not sure if you wanted to do a factory with the `GetPoints`, but this is not a swift pattern.

```
for i in slew {
    var x = i[0]
    var y = i[1]
    pointsArray.append(Points.Point(x:x,y:y)) 
}

class Points: NSObject {
    struct Point {
        var x = Double(0.0)
        var y = Double(0.0)
    }
}
```

To make it even more swifty you can use `CGPoint` instead of your own point and make the for into a map.

```
pointsArray = slew.map { CGPoint(x: $0[0], y: $0[1]) }
```

Comment: thank you very much, although `CGPoint` still quite new to me, I think I have to read more about it

Comment: @Alistra Why nest `struct Point` within `class Points`?

Comment: This was just a modification of the OP's code, I recommend using `CGPoint`